# マルチインデックスでidxmaxを利用する方法

Tags: python, pandas

マルチインデックスなDataFrameから、最大値と、そのインデックスを取得するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？
最大値は、df.max(axis='columns', level='種別')で取得できそうなのですが、
idxmaxは引数にlevelを指定できないようで、困っています。

以下の方法が思いついたのですが、どちらもパフォーマンスを損なう気がしています。

1. stackして列数を減らしてidxmaxする。
2. groupbyでlevel=0の列ごとに最大値を取得する。

他に良い方法がないか、教えていただけないでしょうか。

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[ [1099, 1000, 2099, 2000], [1199, 1100, 2100, 2199], [1200, 1299, 2200, 2299] ],
    index=[ '2021/01', '2021/02', '2021/03' ],
    columns=[ ['りんご', 'りんご', 'みかん', 'みかん'], ['有機', 'ハウス', '有機', 'ハウス'] ],
)
df = df.rename_axis('date', axis='index')
df = df.rename_axis(['果物', '種別'], axis='columns')
display(df)

print('')
print('↓↓↓ 期待する最大値算出結果（level=0の列の最大値と、その種別を取得したい。）')
df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[ [ 1099, '有機', 2099, '有機' ], [ 1199, '有機', 2199, 'ハウス' ], [ 1299, 'ハウス', 2299, 'ハウス' ] ],
    index=[ '2021/01', '2021/02', '2021/03' ],
    columns=[ ['りんご', 'りんご', 'みかん', 'みかん'], ['価格', '種別', '価格', '種別'] ],
)
display(df_out)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def aggregate_maximum(x):
  i = int(x[0] < x[1])
  return pd.Series((x[i], x.index[i][1]), index=('価格', '種別'))

df_out = (
  df.groupby(level=0, sort=False, axis=1)
    .apply(lambda x: x.apply(aggregate_maximum, axis=1)))

print(df_out)

#
果物         りんご         みかん        
          価格    種別   価格    種別
date                                 
2021/01   1099    有機   2099    有機
2021/02   1199    有機   2199   ハウス
2021/03   1299   ハウス  2299   ハウス
```

Comment: pandas1.1.5(GoogleColabに搭載されているVersion)では、
applyの行でcannot reindex from a duplicate axisとエラーが発生しましたので、
pandas1.3.0(JupyterLab)で確認したところ、期待結果を得ることができました。
ありがとうございます。